# Rename feature for EMF Resources

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf

I'm working with a project, where I have EMF model 'A' which is referenced in many other models 'B','C'... etc. What I want is I want to give a rename feature for these resources. So when user renames 'A', its references have to be updated.

Please provide some idea on it, if there is any frame work for this or I have to get all the references and then programmatically iterate and update the references.

Comment: Did you try to play with EMF observer/notifications? You could register observer and react to specific events (as, for example, a set of a name feature on a resource).

Comment: May I  know what kind of update you want to perform in 'B',  'C' etc.,  when you change the name of any attribute, and if that attribute value is consider for FQN in reference, then it would automatically be up updated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem in another way.

The fundamental problem is that a referenced resource file might be renamed, and this breaks the references.

Instead of a refactoring that automatically updates all references I created a *Repair File References* command, which the user can invoke on an edited model.

The command performs these steps:

1. Prompts the user to select a missing resource to repair
2. Prompts the user to select a replacement file
3. Updates all objects in the model that has a proxy URI that matches the missing resource. Replaces proxies with resolved objects in the new resource.

If you still want to make a refactoring instead, I think you anyway can use my code as a starting point.

```java
/**
 * Locates and fixes unresolved references in a model.
 */
public class ReferenceRepairer {
    public static final String COMMAND_ID = Activator.PLUGIN_ID + ".commands.repairReferences";

    /**
     * 1) Prompts the user to select a missing resource to repair
     * 2) Prompts the user to select a replacement file
     * 3) Updates all objects in the model with a proxy URI that matches the missing resource. Replaces proxies
     *    with resolved objects in the new resource.  
     */
    public static void repairResourceReference(Shell shell, EditingDomain editingDomain) {
        Resource res = promptMissingResource(shell, editingDomain);

        if (res == null) return;

        IFile newFile = promptReplacementFile(shell);

        if (newFile == null) return;

        repairReferences(editingDomain, res, URI.createPlatformResourceURI(newFile.getFullPath().toString(), true));
    }

    private static void repairReferences(final EditingDomain editingDomain, Resource missingRes, final URI newUri) {
        URI missingUri = missingRes.getURI();

        // Create new resource for the replacement file
        Resource newRes = editingDomain.getResourceSet().getResource(newUri, true);

        Map<EObject, Collection<Setting>> proxies = UnresolvedProxyCrossReferencer.find(editingDomain.getResourceSet());

        CompoundCommand repairRefsCommand =  new CompoundCommand("Repair references") {
            /**
             * Disallow undo. The model changes could be undone, but it seems impossible to
             * recreate a non-existent resource in the resource set. 
             */
            @Override
            public boolean canUndo() {
                return false;
            }
        };

        // Resolve all proxies from this resource and repair reference to those objects

        for (Entry<EObject, Collection<Setting>> entry : proxies.entrySet()) {

            EObject proxy = entry.getKey();
            URI proxyUri = EcoreUtil.getURI(proxy);
            if (!proxyUri.trimFragment().equals(missingUri)) continue;

            EObject resolved = newRes.getEObject(proxyUri.fragment());

            if (resolved.eIsProxy()) continue;

            // Update all objects that have references to the resolved proxy

            for (Setting sett : entry.getValue()) {
                if (sett.getEStructuralFeature().isMany()) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    EList<Object> valueList = (EList<Object>) sett.get(true);
                    int proxyIx = valueList.indexOf(proxy);

                    repairRefsCommand.append(SetCommand.create(editingDomain,
                        sett.getEObject(), sett.getEStructuralFeature(), resolved, proxyIx));
                } else {
                    repairRefsCommand.append(SetCommand.create(editingDomain,
                        sett.getEObject(), sett.getEStructuralFeature(), resolved));
                }
            }
        }

        if (!repairRefsCommand.isEmpty()) {
            editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute(repairRefsCommand);
        }

        // Remove the 
        editingDomain.getResourceSet().getResources().remove(missingRes);
    }

    private static IFile promptReplacementFile(Shell shell) {
        ElementTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementTreeSelectionDialog(shell, 
            new WorkbenchLabelProvider(), new WorkbenchContentProvider()); 

        dialog.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
        dialog.setTitle("Select Replacement Resource");
        dialog.setMessage("Select a file which will replace the missing file.");

        dialog.setValidator(new ISelectionStatusValidator() {
            @Override
            public IStatus validate(Object[] selection) {
                if (selection.length == 0 || !(selection[0] instanceof IFile)) {
                    return ValidationStatus.error("The selected object is not a file.");
                }

                return new Status(IStatus.OK, Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "");
            }
        });


        if (dialog.open() != Window.OK) return null;

        return (IFile) dialog.getFirstResult();
    }

    private static Resource promptMissingResource(Shell shell, EditingDomain editingDomain) {
        ElementListSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementListSelectionDialog(shell, 
                new LabelProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public String getText(Object elem) {
                        return ((Resource) elem).getURI().toString();
                    }
            })
        {
            /** Make dialog OK button enabled when there are errors, instead of vise-versa. */ 
            @Override
            protected void updateButtonsEnableState(IStatus status) {
                Button okButton = getOkButton();
                if (okButton != null && !okButton.isDisposed()) {
                    okButton.setEnabled(!status.isOK());
                }
            }

            /** Disable filter text field */
            @Override
            protected Text createFilterText(Composite parent) {
                Text text = super.createFilterText(parent);
                text.setSize(0, 0);
                text.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().exclude(true).create());
                text.setVisible(false);
                return text;
            }
        };

        dialog.setTitle("Select Missing Resource");
        dialog.setMessage(
            "Select a URI of a missing resource file that should be replaced by an URI to an existing file.");
        dialog.setElements(getMissingResources(editingDomain.getResourceSet().getResources()).toArray());

        if (dialog.open() != Window.OK) return null;

        return (Resource) dialog.getFirstResult();
    }

    private static List<Resource> getMissingResources(List<Resource> resources) {
        List<Resource> missingResources = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Resource res : resources) {
            try {
                if (res.getURI().isPlatformPlugin()) continue;
                URL url = FileLocator.toFileURL(new URL(res.getURI().toString()));
                java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(url.getProtocol(), "", "/" + url.getPath(), null);
                if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(uri))) {
                    missingResources.add(res);
                }
            } catch (InvalidPathException | IOException | URISyntaxException exc) {
                // Ignore. There mighe be weird Sirius resource in the resources set which we can't recognice
            }

        }
        return missingResources;
    }
}
```